# Power BI embed an invoice viewer for finance report

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, data-analysis, finance, business-intelligence

i am working on an accounting report, i wonder if somehow we can embed an invoice viewer inside the report so when we click on some visual it automatically shows the invoice or receipt or any other document related to that transaction ??
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can first create an invoice report with an Invoice # parameter, for example, and hide that report. Next configure any visual on your Accounting Report that uses Invoice #...you can configure that element to show the invoice report as Tooltip when you hover.(Visual.General.ToolTips.OptionType.ReportPage)
[image]

Likewise you can create a receipts report and setup tool tips to use it, too! Have fun.